# Shader framebuffer readback

Tags: glsl, hlsl, pixel-shader, fragment-shader

I was wondering if there is support in the newer shader models to read-back a pixel value from the target framebuffer. I assume that this is alrdy done in later (non-programmable) stages in the drawing pipeline which made me hope that this feature might have been added into the programmable pipeline.

I am aware that it is possible to draw to a texture bound framebuffer and then send this texture to the shader, I was just hoping for a more elegant way to achieve the same functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Andrew notes, the framebuffer access is logically a separate stage from the fragment shader, so reading the framebuffer in the fragment shader is impossible.  The reason for this (to answer Andrew's question) is a combination of performance and the ordering requirements of the graphics pipeline.  The way the rendering pipeline is defined, framebuffer blending operations MUST occur in the same order as the triangles/primitives that went into the beginning of the pipeline.  The fragment shaders, on the other hand, can happen in any order.  So by having them be separate stages, the GPU is free to run fragment shaders as fast as it can, as their inputs become available, without having to synchronize between them.  As long as it maintains enough bufffer space to hold on to the outputs of the fragment shaders, so that they can be accumulated and allow the framebuffer blends and writes to occur in order, all is well, as the results of any given fragment shader are not visible until after the blending stage.

If there was a way for the fragment shader to read the framebuffer, it would require some sort of synchronization to ensure that those reads happen in order, thus greatly slowing things down.

Answer (score 4):

No. As you mention, rendering to a texture is the way to achieve that functionality.

If you take a look at a block diagram of a GPU pipeline, you'll see that the blending stage - which is what combines fragment shader output with the framebuffer - is separate from the fragment shader and is fixed-function.

I'm not a GPU designer - so I can only speculate the reason for this. Presumably it is to keep framebuffer access fast and insulate the fragment shader stage from the frame buffer so that it can be better parallelised. There are probably also issues regarding multi-sampling, and so on.

(Not to mention that fixed-function blending is "good enough" in most cases.)

Answer (score 3):

Actually I think this is now doable with Direct3D 11 SM 5.0 (I didn't test it though).

You can bind an UAV to a PS 5.0, for allowing read and write operations on it using method `OMSetRenderTargetsAndUnorderedAccessViews`.

In that case the backbuffer of the swap chain in which you render has to be created with flag `DXGI_USAGE_UNORDERED_ACCESS` (I guess).

This is used in DXSDK OIT11 sample.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to read back the contents of the frame buffer in the fragment shader with Shader_framebuffer_fetch extension. The support can be added to the GPU with some performance loss. In fact, these days I'm working on to add the support of this extension in the OpenGL ES2.0 driver of a well known GPU brand in the consumer electronics market.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw to a texture TEX (using a render target view) and then bind that as an input to another shader (using a shader resource view). TEX is then a pseduo-framebuffer.